# Retrieve metadata from aws cli for LaunchConfiguration and Autoscaling

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services

I am trying to write a bash script which is going update the autoscaling group(min, max and desired count), in order to do so, need some values from aws metadeta, below will be the command to update the autoscaling group:

```
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name <AutoScalingGroupName> --launch-configuration-name <LaunchConfigurationName> --min-size 2 --max-size 8 --vpc-zone-identifier <SubnetID>
```

In above command, I am able to get Autoscaling group name, somehow not able to find LaunchConfigurationName from aws metadata, below is the example:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1x-82-xx ~]$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-id,Values=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key== 'aws:autoscaling:groupName'].Value]" --output text
Venus-stack-LCname-1SO0L0117ML51

[ec2-user@ip-10-134-82-105 ~]$  aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-id,Values=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query Reservations[].Instances[].SubnetId[] --output text
subnet-c87aa4e7
```

Is there any possibility to get all three values(AutoScalingGroupName>, , ) from single command, which will be passed into my script.

Also, please help me to find out LaunchConfigurationName from aws cli, thanks in advance

Thanks
Aryan

Comment: What's the goal here?

Comment: @strongjz My Goal here to write a bash script for updating the minimum, maximum and desired count of AutoScalingGroup and Services in a cluster.

Comment: A better practice would be to send a custom metric to cloudwatch and have the Autoscaling group scale based on that metric. What are you tracking or how do you know when to kick off the bash script to scale? Here is how to create and send custom metrics http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html